# "Variable does not live long enough" when returning a Result containing a reference but it does live long enough

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm implementing a small utility and the compiler is telling me that a variable (a `TcpStream`) does not live long enough and is advising me to find a way to make it live exactly as long as it is currently living.

## Error message

```
error[E0597]: `stream` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:47:35
   |
47 |         match handle_request(&mut stream){
   |                                   ^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
54 | }
   | - borrowed value only lives until here
   |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the function body at 43:1...
  --> src/main.rs:43:1
   |
43 | / fn handle_array(stream: &mut BufReader<TcpStream>) -> Result<Data,Errors>
44 | | {
45 | |     let mut array: Vec<Data> = Vec::with_capacity(50);//arbitrary size, picked differently in the complete program
46 | |     for _x in 0..50 {
...  |
53 | |     Ok(Data::Array(array))
54 | | }
   | |_^
```

## Code

[Rust playground snippet with the exact problem](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=a82bf136f9dce9fc829dc9694417e3d5&version=stable&mode=debug)

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::io::BufReader;
use std::io::Read;
use std::net::TcpStream;

static TOKEN: &[u8; 2] = b"\r\n";

fn main() {}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub enum Data {
    String(Vec<u8>),
    Error(Vec<u8>),
    Integer(i64),
    Binary(Vec<u8>),
    Array(Vec<Data>),
    Dictionary(HashMap<String, Data>),
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub enum Errors<'a> {
    CommandError(&'a str),
    EndOfConnection,
    NotImplemented,
}

pub fn handle_request(stream: &mut BufReader<TcpStream>) -> Result<Data, Errors> {
    //TODO handle the empty stream
    let mut buff: [u8; 1] = *b"0";
    stream.read_exact(&mut buff); //TODO: handle error here
    match &buff {
        /* part skipped, not relevant */
        b"*" => handle_array(stream),
        &[_] => Err(Errors::CommandError("Bad request")),
    }
}

/*part skipped, not relevant  */

fn handle_array(stream: &mut BufReader<TcpStream>) -> Result<Data, Errors> {
    let mut array: Vec<Data> = Vec::with_capacity(50); //arbitrary size, picked differently in the complete program
    for _x in 0..50 {
        match handle_request(&mut stream) {
            Ok(x) => array.push(x.clone()),
            Err(x) => return Err(x.clone()),
        }
    }

    Ok(Data::Array(array))
}
```

I'm really stuck on this one.

It seems that I can't use the value of the Err. If I replace

```
match handle_request(&mut stream){
    Ok(x) => array.push(x.clone()),
    Err(x) => return Err(x.clone()),
}
```

with

```
match handle_request(&mut stream){
    Ok(x) => array.push(x.clone()),
    Err(_) => return Err(Errors::NotImplemented),
}
```

the problem is solved, but I don't know why.

Comment: @Shepmaster is it better now ? I really want to make this the right way :)

Comment: Additionally, why are there so many enum variants; are all of them needed? Are the calls to various functions needed? Is `TOKEN` used? And so on...

Comment: Now it compile, i will simplify it more. You're right, it's still bloated.

Comment: Just found a solution, I will continue to simplify this code later and post the solution as soon as I find out exactly why my "solution" works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem can be reduced to this:

```
struct Reader;
struct Data;
struct Errors<'a>(&'a str);

fn handle_array(stream: &mut Reader) -> Result<Data, Errors> {
    for _ in 0..0 {
        handle_request(&mut stream)?;
    }

    unimplemented!();
}

fn handle_request(_stream: &mut Reader) -> Result<Data, Errors> {
    unimplemented!()
}

fn main() {}
```

```
error[E0597]: `stream` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:7:29
   |
7  |         handle_request(&mut stream)?;
   |                             ^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
11 | }
   | - borrowed value only lives until here
   |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the function body at 5:1...
  --> src/main.rs:5:1
   |
5  | / fn handle_array(stream: &mut Reader) -> Result<Data, Errors> {
6  | |     for _ in 0..0 {
7  | |         handle_request(&mut stream)?;
8  | |     }
9  | |
10 | |     unimplemented!();
11 | | }
   | |_^
```

In the body of `handle_array`, `stream` is of type `&mut Reader`. However, when calling `handle_request`, you *take another reference to it*, creating a `&mut &mut Reader`.

Adding some explicit lifetimes to the code (for educational purposes, this doesn't compile), the code would look kind of like this:

```
fn handle_array<'stream>(stream: &'stream mut Reader) -> Result<Data, Errors> {
    let tmp: &'tmp mut &'stream mut Reader = &mut stream;
    if let Err(x) = handle_request(tmp)
```

`handle_request` requires a `&mut Reader`, so the compiler inserts some code to align these two types for you. The compiler has to be conservative about how it performs this conversion, so it picks the shorter lifetime:

```
fn handle_array<'stream>(stream: &'stream mut Reader) -> Result<Data, Errors> {
    let tmp: &'tmp mut &'stream mut Reader = &mut stream;
    let tmp2: &'tmp mut Reader = tmp;
    if let Err(x) = handle_request(tmp2)
```

The next aspect of the problem is that *lifetime elision* has kicked in for both functions. Their expanded forms look like:

```
fn handle_array<'stream>(stream: &'stream mut Reader) -> Result<Data, Errors<'stream>>

fn handle_request<'_stream>(_stream: &_stream mut Reader) -> Result<Data, Errors<'_stream>>
```

This means that the lifetime of the returned `Errors` is tied to the lifetime of the argument, but in your case, the argument to `handle_request` has the shorter `'tmp` lifetime, *not* the lifetime of `'stream`. This shows why you get the compiler error: You are trying to return an `Errors` that can only live *inside the function* (the lifetime of the variable `stream` itself), but you are trying to return a reference that needs to live longer.

We can solve this by only passing `stream` to `handle_request`:

```
handle_request(stream)?;
```

Unfortunately, this only changes the error:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*stream` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:9:40
   |
9  |         if let Err(x) = handle_request(stream) {
   |                                        ^^^^^^ mutable borrow starts here in previous iteration of loop
...
15 | }
   | - mutable borrow ends here
```

This part is *much* harder to explain. See:

- "Problem Case #3" of the [Non-Lexical Lifetimes RFC (RFC 2094)](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2094-nll.md)
- [Cannot borrow `x` as mutable more than once at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31281155/155423)
- [Cannot borrow node as mutable more than once while implementing a binary search tree](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38043377/155423)

This is a really rough edge of Rust's right now, but it's getting closer and closer to being fixed! Right now, however, you have two main choices:

#### Call the function twice

This probably won't work because you can't read from the stream twice, but in other cases it might be useful:

```
fn handle_array(stream: &mut Reader) -> Result<Data, Errors> {
    let mut array = vec![];
    for _ in 0..0 {
        if handle_request(stream).is_err() {
            return handle_request(stream);
        }
        if let Ok(r) = handle_request(stream) {
            array.push(r);
        };
    }

    unimplemented!();
}
```

#### Remove the references

Give up on trying to have references in this case *for now*.

```
struct Errors(String);

fn handle_array(stream: &mut Reader) -> Result<Data, Errors> {
    let mut array = vec![];
    for _ in 0..0 {
        array.push(handle_request(stream)?);
    }

    unimplemented!();
}
```

Which I'd write using iterators for efficiency:

```
fn handle_array(stream: &mut Reader) -> Result<Data, Errors> {
    let array = (0..0)
        .map(|_| handle_request(stream))
        .collect::<Result<Vec<_>, _>>()?;

    unimplemented!();
}
```

#### The future?

With the *unstable* NLL feature and the *experimental* "Polonius" implementation, this code works:

```
struct Errors<'a>(&'a str);

fn handle_array(stream: &mut Reader) -> Result<Data, Errors> {
    let mut array = vec![];
    for _ in (0..0) {
        array.push(handle_request(stream)?);
    }

    unimplemented!();
}
```

It will just be a while before this is generally available...

Comment: Thanks a lot, It seems that I still have a lot to learn in rust. Great response , with a lot of details; cannot have dreamed of better :)